# Angular application shows errors from undefined:1?

Tags: angular

[undefined:1 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxiUu.png)

I seek help for this error which comes very often in my angular application at various places.
It says

GET http://localhost:8080/undefined 404 (Not Found) and comes from undefined:1 (You can check in the image also) where 8080 is my node backend server. This error comes in many components and i am not sure how it is occuring. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is running on localhost:8080? If it's your backend, where is your Angular app trying to make requests to the backend from a dynamic URL? The "undefined" looks like you're trying to use a string that doesn't exist to build a GET call.

Comment: please add some code to your question, and more detail about your server !!

Comment: @ZINEMahmoud Actually code doesn't contain any of such undefined call and what part of the code i need to put i am also not sure because it comes at many places.

Comment: @WillAlexander I have edited the question, yes it is my backend server.

Comment: @AbhijeetRaj you have to past the angular wich call the server and the parameter you pass to it , it can be that you pass a variable as endpoint which is not well defined